# Python read file in while loop

Tags: python, file-io, while-loop

I am currently in some truble regarding python and reading files. I have to open a file in a while loop and do some stuff with the values of the file. The results are written into a new file. This new file is then read in the next run of the while loop. But in this second run I get no values out of this file... Here is a code snippet, that hopefully clarifies what I mean.

```
while convergence == 0:
    run += 1
    prevrun = run-1

    if os.path.isfile("./Output/temp/EmissionMat%d.txt" %prevrun) == True:
        matfile = open("./Output/temp/EmissionMat%d.txt" %prevrun, "r") 
        EmissionMat = Aux_Functions.EmissionMat(matfile)
        matfile.close()
    else:
        matfile = open("./Input/EmissionMat.txt", "r") 
        EmissionMat = Aux_Functions.EmissionMat(matfile)
        matfile.close()

    # now some valid operations, which produce a matrix

    emissionmat_file = open("./output/temp/EmissionMat%d.txt" %run, "w")
    emissionmat_file.flush()
    emissionmat_file.write(str(matrix))

    emissionmat_file.close()
```

---

Solved it!

```
matfile.seek(0)
```

This resets the pointer to the begining of the file and allows me to read the file in the next run correctly.

---

Comment: why do you `emissionmat_file.flush()` before writing, and what is the content of `matrix`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @interjay I am using Win7.

Comment: @njzk2 I do emissionmat_file.flush() to get the content to my file otherwise i get no values in my file. The content of matrix is a numpy array with 40*40 values. But do not mind the write stuff. The resulting file looked as it is desired. I just simplified it here.

Comment: do you have a typo in your code? "./Output" and "./output" is not the same... pro tip: use a constant/variable for this...

Comment: @DarenThomas: isn't NTFS case-insensitive?

Comment: @DarenThomas Yes, there is this typo, I corrected it, but it does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why to write to a file and then read it ? Moreover you use flush, so you are doing potentially long io. I would do

```
with open(originalpath) as f:
    mat = f.read()
while condition :
    run += 1
    write_mat_run(mat, run)
    mat = func(mat)
```

write_mat_run may be done in another thread. You should check io exceptions.

BTW this will probably solve your bug, or at least make it clear.

Comment: This is part of an expectation maximization algorithm so i need the values from the previous run for the current run.

Comment: I solved it (see question post) I will post it as a "real" answer if the system allows me to. But thanks for your help!

Comment: With this pattern you use the previous run for the current one. It may be really more efficient because IO is a bottleneck and can kill you performances and less bug prone since you don't have to rely on the filesystem. Even if you solved your bug I suggest you to use this pattern.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. I honestly have not thought of the prefomance issue, so thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice. I changed it the way you suggested it an it really improves the speed of the computation and also solves another error I got. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see nothing wrong with your code. The following concrete example worked on my Linux machine:

```
import os

run = 0
while run < 10:
    run += 1
    prevrun = run-1

    if os.path.isfile("output%d.txt" %prevrun):
        matfile = open("output%d.txt" %prevrun, "r")
        data = matfile.readlines()
        matfile.close()
    else:
        matfile = open("input.txt", "r")
        data = matfile.readlines()
        matfile.close()

    data = [ s[:-1] + "!\n" for s in data ]

    emissionmat_file = open("output%d.txt" %run, "w")
    emissionmat_file.writelines(data)
    emissionmat_file.close()
```

It adds an exclamation mark to each line in the file `input.txt`.

Comment: As you can see in the question post I solved the problem. I will put it in a "real" answer as soon as the system allows me to do this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it

before closing the file I do

```
matfile.seek(0)
```

This solved my problem. This methods sets the pointer of the reader to the beginning.